# Initializing a dynamic array with a raw array

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, initialization

I have a dynamic array class, for which I would like to implement a functionality of initializing the dynamic array directly with a raw array, similar to `std::vector`.

```
struct Array {
   int *ptr = NULL;
   int size;
   int capacity;
   
   Array() : size(0), capacity(0) {}
   Array(int capacity) : size(0), capacity(capacity) {
       ptr = (int*)malloc(capacity*sizeof(int));
   }
};
```

We can initialize `std::vector` using a raw array like this:

```
 std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

It seems that `std::vector` uses `std::initializer_list` to accomplish this. Is it possible to achieve the same result without using the STL library? Such that I can initialize it like this:

```
Array array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

or

```
Array array {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

If this is not possible without `std::initializer_list`, how can I copy the elements from it to the dynamic array?

Comment: Consider reading a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), a good [C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) then using standard [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) such as `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: With recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org) C++ compilers, **the implementation of `std::vector` is open source, so study its source code.**

Comment: Also, your `ptr` should better be initialialized with `new` and destroyed with `delete`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
Array array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

is not initializing using a raw array. this uses an initializer list or a uniform initializer. If you want to use a raw array, you must define it firstly, like what follows.

I used templates and passing by reference to deduce the size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Array {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    int *ptr = nullptr;

    template<size_t n>
    Array(int (&arr) [n]):size{n}, capacity{2*size}, ptr{ new int[capacity]}{

        std::copy(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr), ptr);
    }
    ~Array(){delete[] ptr;}
};

int main(){
    int arr [] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Array array = arr;
    std::for_each(array.ptr, array.ptr+array.size, [](auto  el){std::cout << el << " ";});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/91bEcP)

And this is another approach (using the uniform initializer), if you want to initialize your class as you showed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Array {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    int *ptr = nullptr;


    template<class ... Args, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<Args...>,int>>>
    Array(Args ... args):size{sizeof...(Args)}, capacity{2*size},ptr{ new int[capacity]}{

        int* temp = ptr;
        ((*(temp++) = args),...);
    }
    ~Array(){delete[] ptr;}
};

int main(){
    Array array = {1,2,3,4};
    std::for_each(array.ptr, array.ptr+array.size, [](auto  el){std::cout << el << " ";});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EvWx5n)

Using `std::initializer_list<int>`, it will be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Array {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    int *ptr = nullptr;


    Array(std::initializer_list<int> && ls):size{ls.size()}, capacity{2*size},ptr{ new int[capacity]}{
        std::copy(ls.begin(), ls.end(), ptr);
    }
    ~Array(){delete[] ptr;}
};

int main(){
    Array array = {1,2,3,4};
    std::for_each(array.ptr, array.ptr+array.size, [](auto  el){std::cout << el << " ";});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tod7W1)

Comment: This is very helpful thank you! If that's actually an initializer list how could we initialize the class using it instead?

Comment: `warning: ‘Array::size’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]`

Comment: Thank @asmmo, he did the heavy lifting. Nice solutions both.

Comment: @asmmo Awesome thanks very much! So template parameter packs is what I needed, didn't know about these! I'm guessing this is how `std::initializer_list` implemented also.

Comment: @LennyWhite "*I'm guessing this is how `std::initializer_list` implemented also.*" - no. An `initializer_list` is a special kind of object that is constructed directly by the compiler itself while parsing user code.